# azure function connect to 3rd party API not working when deployed

Tags: python, azure

I have a simple Azure func defined like this:

```
import logging
import cdsapi
import azure.functions as func
import sys

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function is about to process request.')
    try:
        cds = cdsapi.Client()
        cds.url="urlgoeshere"
        cds.key="keygoeshere"

        cds.retrieve("reanalysis-era5-pressure-levels",
        {
        "variable": "temperature",
        "pressure_level": "1000",
        "product_type": "reanalysis",
        "year": "2008",
        "month": "01",
        "day": "01",
        "time": "12:00",
        "format": "grib"
        },"download.grib")
        return func.HttpResponse(
                "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.",
                status_code=200
            )
    except:
        logging.info("  error!", sys.exc_info()[0], "occurred.")
```

My intention is to retrieve data under `cds.retrieve` command.
When I debug it from visual studio code it works perfectly.
But when I deploy it to Azure function via VS code it doesnt work at all.
I get following error:

```
2020-09-02T16:01:45Z   [Information]   Executing 'Functions.azure-cds' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=ae0df178-f726-461e-aca7-8ada6995feaa)
2020-09-02T16:01:45Z   [Verbose]   Sending invocation id:ae0df178-f726-461e-aca7-8ada6995feaa
2020-09-02T16:01:45Z   [Verbose]   Posting invocation id:ae0df178-f726-461e-aca7-8ada6995feaa on workerId:e365cae7-bb7c-4f14-92b9-82b5cb77334b
2020-09-02T16:01:45Z   [Information]   Python HTTP trigger function is about to process request.
2020-09-02T16:01:45Z   [Error]   Executed 'Functions.azure-cds' (Failed, Id=ae0df178-f726-461e-aca7-8ada6995feaa, Duration=9ms)
```

In `requirements.txt` i have added dependencies:

```
azure-functions
cdsapi
```

It seems like 3rd party API needs to be adjusted somehow in azure portal
Any help in resolving this is appreciated.

Comment: `azure-cds` is your function name?

Comment: Yes. azure-cds is function name.

Comment: Ok, What I would suggest is to put a `try except` just after the first logging statement  and  log the error to the console if any exception occurs, so that you can see what exception cause the function to be failed.

Comment: I didn manage to catch exception, but Azure portal console output gave following error: HTTP response code
500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Can you post the updated the code as well?

Comment: Updated. Together with api key exposed.

Comment: Can you show the detail error? It seems that the error message you gave is not complete.

Comment: Above shown is all Logs shows. I am now reading help regarding creating proxy port for routing API requests to it. Here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-serverless-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this I had to edit source code in `cdsapi` package. This is because API is by default set to  search for `/.cdsapirc` file in local machine. This is file where `url` and `key` are stored.
This environment and file cannot be reproduced in cloud azure function.
What I did is simply setting `url` and `key` to empty string in `__init__` method inside `Client` class,and later setting them to appropriate values.